# ARM MCUs in hobbyist-friendly packages (DIP, SOIC)

Tags: arm

**UPD Please do not answer or comment it anymore**, the question is too broad and not valid. Since I asked it I get used to using STM32 chips with handmade PCBs (so it's rather an issue of improving etching skills).

---

This surely was asked several times, but I see the information is generally outdated.

I wonder what ARM chips now exist in DIP or SOIC packages so that I can use them in either bread-board or fast hand-drawn pcb-prototype. E.g. with distance between pins no less than 1mm.

As for DIP's, there seems to be only two famous: LPC1114 (28 pins) and LPC810 (8 pins)

With SOIC situation looks bit better, I've found so far LCP1110, LPC1112 in 20-pin packages (which cost almost the same price as my favorite ATMega8L) and could be programmed via UART which is quite convenient.

Surprisingly Atmel have several ATSAM9... and ATSAM10... in SOIC-14 and SOIC-20 - regretfully I have no experience with them yet. Probably I'll try soon.

If you are acquainted with any other (excluding tiny evaluation boards), could you please help me extend this small list?

Comment: Flagging this as off-topic since it relies solely on current ARM MCUs in these packages and there isn't a clear question relating to the design of electronics.  These types of things go out of date very quickly as some parts go EOL and new ones come.  The flag may get rejected though since I'm honestly not sure if the mods will want to keep this one.

Comment: I think "very quickly" is an exaggeration. The microcontroller market moves relatively slowly.

Comment: AFAIK (and I am very interested and keep a very open eye) the LPC1114 and LPC810 are the only ARM (or rather: Cortex M) chips in DIP. I wish there were more. Microchip makes a hughe range of 32-bit chips in DIP, but alas, those are MIPs, not ARM/Cortex.

Comment: Maybe QFP would also be a good choice for you? It's not harder to hand-solder than SOIC.

Comment: Most modern QFPs have considerablly smaller pin spacing than SOIC.

Answer (score 3):

Given the general evolution of packages (in general, not just ARM) towards ever-smaller SMT, it's IMHO a good idea to get used to the idea that soldering an SMT into a DIP adapter board is potentially part of having access to many chips/parts in a means that's convenient to play with.

The adapter boards are pretty common items in the wild. I suppose someone could possibly offer adapter boards with pre-soldered parts, but the premium would have to be fairly high to make that pay, I suspect.

Alternate approach is to face up to spinning a board to play with a part, perhaps leaving a bunch of options open (toss in unpopulated pads and outside connections.)